# Convert string to float pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Simple question: I have a dataset, imported from a csv file, containing a string column with numeric values. After the comma are decimal places.

I want to convert to float. Basically,it's just this:

```
x = ['27,10083']
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df.astype(float)
```

Why does this not work and how to fix this simple issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assign output with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df = df.replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float)
```

If want specify columns for converting:

```
cols = ['col1','col2']
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Another solution is use parameter `decimal=','` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), then columns are correctly parsed to floats:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, decimal=',')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,used the decimal=',' in the csv import, great.

Comment: I am using the following parramters in `read_csv`:  `skiprows=9, sep=None,  decimal=',', engine='python'`` then decimal does not work. Any idea why ?